# How to sort files from glob search results in the order they appear in Windows explorer?

Tags: python, file

I'm searching a dir and I tried different things, `glob`, `pathlib.Path`, 'listdir` etc. However, search results are not ordered they way they appear. I looked it up and suggestions were to resort it to the way you want. But what is the way that makes it look like it appears in Windows?

Concretely, here are the files
And here are the search results
I tried sorting by time, by data modified, but none gave me that Windows order.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the second image is expected output? and can you clarify what exactly "Windows order" and it would be good if you show an example

Comment: @deadshot No. If this is what I want, then we're done. The second image is what you get from `glob` and others. What do I mean exactly by "Windows order"? I mean the order you see in the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path

result = Path('/content/data').glob('*.png')
print(sorted(result, key = lambda x: [int(k) if k.isdigit() else k for k in re.split('([0-9]+)', x.stem)]))
```

**Output:**

```
[PosixPath('/content/data/1.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/1blah.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/2.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/3.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/4.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/5.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/6.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/7.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/8.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/9.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/10.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/11.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/12.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/14.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/15.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/16.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/17.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/18.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/19.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/20.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/21.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/22.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/23.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/24.png'),
 PosixPath('/content/data/untitled.png')]
```

Comment: I think this is bandage-aid solution. Is it going to work in all scenarios or is it specific to this folder? I just added `1blah.png` and it failed.

Comment: Perfect. I think Windows Explorer is doing this enternally lol